# Not able to do any action after launching the application on IE8 using webdriver

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using
Selenium standalone server - 2.25.0
IE - 8.0.6001.18702 (32-bit)
IEDriverServer - 2.25.1.0
Java - SDK6
OS - Win Xp 32-bit

Code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "Path to IEDriverServer.exe");
    driver.get("http://www.naukri.com/");
     // Used Wait before entering text.
    driver.findElement(By.id("qp")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("qp")).sendKeys("java j2ee");
    driver.findElement(By.id("ql")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ql")).sendKeys("chennai");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create a new Job Alert")).click();
```

I used above code to launch IE8. I was able to launch and open the application successfully in IE. But, after that i am not able to do any actions on the opened web page.

1. I did IE protected mode settings to high level for all the four.
2. Set the path for IEDriverServer.exe
3. Set the browser zoom level to 100%

I did all the above and i read many forums but i didn't get the answer.

I used the same code and run in an another machine. It works fine there. The second machine configuration is

Selenium standalone server - 2.25.0
IE - 8.0.7601.17514 (64-bit)
IEDriverServer - 2.25.1.0
Java - SDK7
OS - Win 7 professional

I don't know what is the exact problem is? I tried to find the root cause but i am not.
Please help me to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: what exceptions you got ? make sure after driver.get("http://www.naukri.com/"); webpage loading completed.  use IE Dev tool to verify nothing in progress after that step.

Comment: i got the exception as `org.openqa.selenium.nosuchelementexception unable to find element with id == qp` (The WebDriver did not provide any stack trace information)

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few things to think about:

Update Selenium, it is at **v2.28**.

Switch to using the **Chrome** or **Firefox** Driver, to see if it's an issue residing with the IEDriver or something else.

You are also misunderstanding what the 'protected mode' of IE means. You are mangling the security zones, this is different.

Refer to this image:

http://www.ivertech.com/images/internetExplorer7/IE7UncheckEnableProtectedModeCheckBox.gif

Each zone will have it's own **protected mode** settings. Uncheck it for all zones.

If you do not have that checkbox there, two things: it's probably disabled by your IT admin, if you have one and therefore there isn't much we can do - you'll have to speak to your IT team, **and** screenshot to show what you *do* have.

Instead of using the implicit timeout, actually wrap it in a `WebDriverWait` condition:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html

If it fails after a reasonable timeout (1 minute), then we know something else is wrong. Don't use the implicit wait functions.

Also see if you can get to the element in a different way, for instance using this CSS selector:

```
input.w327
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm very sure i am facing the problem only on IE alone. AS you suggest I goggled and found that there is no option to see `Enable Protected mode` check boxes on IE8 using Win Xp. Those check boxes will available only on Win 7 and above.  I tried both implicit and explicit wait. nothing sounds good.

Comment: You said in your original post you are running Win 7 Professional.

Comment: I said i am getting result when i used Win 7 and i am not getting result while i used win Xp. Please read the post again.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message u got, you are entering the values in the field before the page is loaded completely. The wait period which u have used is enough load the page. use this

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or

increase the wait period.
if you are using Thread.sleep(10000); in your code, then increase it to Thread.sleep(20000);
It will work.

Comment: I tried up to 40 seconds. Nothing sounds good still i am getting error.

Comment: Did the page loaded completely before the error displayed. And did u try using this code "driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)";

Comment: yes. I tried the above code in two machine. It works in one and not in the another one. I don't know what is the exact problem and why it works in one box and not in another one.

Comment: It is the sync. problem i guess. Try to sync. the timing in your both system. if not use the xpath instead of id attribute.

Comment: What do you mean by synchronization? How to achieve? I tried all the element locators. Nothings works.

Comment: Try to increase the wait period in the system where it is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But as i said before i tried `wait` it's not working.

Comment: for the second machine IE SecurityZones are same for all ?

Comment: @Stale: Yeah. I am using IE8. So, there is no check boxes to enable or disable. But, i raised all the zone level to high.